# Azure storage sdk v1.3 to v2 => SetConfigurationSettingPublisher

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

How could you convert this in Azure storage v2.0 since "SetConfigurationSettingPublisher" was deleted ?

```
CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher( 
( configName, configSetter ) =>
{
  // Provide the configSetter with the initial value
  configSetter( RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue( configName ) );

  RoleEnvironment.Changed += ( sender, arg ) =>
  {
    if( arg.Changes.OfType<RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingChange>( ).Any( (change) => 
        ( change.ConfigurationSettingName == configName ) ) )
    {
      // The corresponding configuration setting has changed, so propagate the value
      if( !configSetter( RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue( configName ) ) )
      {
        // In this case, the change to the storage account credentials in the
        // service configuration is significant enough that the role needs to be
        // recycled in order to use the latest settings (for example, the 
        // endpoint may have changed)
        RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle();
      }
    }
  };
}
```

);

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 Breaking Changes & Migration Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx):

> CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher has been removed. Instead the members of [StorageCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.auth.storagecredentials.aspx) are now mutable allowing users to accomplish similar scenarios in a more streamlined manner by simply mutating the StorageCredentials instance associated with a given client(s) via the provided UpdateKey methods.

Depending on your application's requirements you might simply use the `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting()` method directly, as described in [Upgrading to Azure Storage Client 2.0](http://www.thedailyparker.com/PermaLink,guid,be55f5e0-a041-4d14-aa7b-2966352ad724.aspx):

```
var someSetting = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(settingKey);
```

If you need to respond to configuration changes while the role instance is running, you can subscribe to the [`RoleEnvironment.Changing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432963.aspx) and [`RoleEnvironment.Changed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433023.aspx) events as described in [Read Configuration Settings for the Storage Client Library and Handle Changed Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg494982.aspx) and [Responding to Role Topology Changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/01/04/responding-to-role-topology-changes.aspx).