# Sending message to Azure queue from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to make a windows application in WPF that needs to send messages to Azure queue that belongs to other cloud application. Later a worker role will extract those messages from the queue and make some manipulation on the data.

- Is it even possible or do I have to use a cloud application with a web role?
- If it is, can someone point me to a good reading source on how to do it?
- If its not, how can I make a windows executable app that uses Azure queues?

**edit:** this is my code, I included this:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;


var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");
var queue = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
```

I get this exception:

```
SetConfigurationSettingPublisher needs to be called before FromConfigurationSetting can be used
```

I've tried to look up this exception but didn't find a normal solution. Every post is talking about an azure cloud application while I'm trying to do it from WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work, with some help from a friend. This is what I did:

Added reference to `System.Configuration` in order to use `ConfigurationManager`

Added to the App.Config:

`<appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1:10001/"/>
  </appSettings>`

In order to connect to local storage account:

`CloudStorageAccount st = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"].ToString());`

Hopes it helps other stuck with same problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can send messages to an Azure queue from anywhere, as long as you have proper permissions to do so. I'm assuming you're talking about Storage queues (vs Service Bus queues): You'd either need the storage account key or a Shared Access Signature for the queue. At that point, you can write messages from whatever app you want to.

Just create the queue client, create your message, and add a message to the queue. If your app is running on-premises, on a mobile device, or in a different data center than the storage account the queue is stored in, there will be a bit of latency when adding the message but, otherwise, works just fine.

Comment: And of course you'll need to install the WindowsAzure.Storage package from NuGet into your WPF application ;)

Comment: The issue is with the way you're retrieving your connection string. Look at [this StackOverflow question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789937/azure-storage-sdk-v1-3-to-v2-setconfigurationsettingpublisher) for more info.