# Convert legacy Azure storage configurationsettingpublisher

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I am trying to update legacy code, which has been leveraging pre-2.0 WindowsAzure.Storage. In the Application_Start, there is the following:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connectionString = "";

        CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher(
          (configName, configSettingPublisher) =>
          {
               connectionString = RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable
                  ? RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName)
                  : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName];
              configSettingPublisher(connectionString);
          });
    }
```

Not sure how this is to be converted to the new method...

Comment: Does this answer cover what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216175/azure-code-to-pull-settings-that-will-work-in-all-three-scenarios-azure-websit/29244154#29244154

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure storage sdk v1.3 to v2 => SetConfigurationSettingPublisher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789937/azure-storage-sdk-v1-3-to-v2-setconfigurationsettingpublisher)

Answer (score 0):

As Serdar has stated, please check out this related question [Azure storage sdk v1.3 to v2 => SetConfigurationSettingPublisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789937/azure-storage-sdk-v1-3-to-v2-setconfigurationsettingpublisher)

Specifically, look at #8 on this link http://www.thedailyparker.com/PermaLink,guid,be55f5e0-a041-4d14-aa7b-2966352ad724.aspx

Hopefully this helps